# Xamarin, Android - App not installed error with signed APK

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, apk, signing

I followed this tutorial:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_1_-_preparing_an_application_for_release/

and this one:
https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/publishing_an_application/part_2_-_signing_the_android_application_package/

So I set the `configuration` to `release` and rebuilt my solution. After that, I archived my project, clicked on the `distribute...` button, selected `Ad Hoc`(So I could upload the APK to my Google Drive) generated a keystore and clicked on the `save as button`. Then I selected a location to save my APK, uploaded it to Google Drive and tried to install it on my phone, but I got this error:

```
X App not installed.
```

How can I fix this problem?

NOTE:

My phone is set to allow installations from unknown sources.
If I install from adb I get this error:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_UPDATE_INCOMPATIBLE]
```

Comment: Is your phone set to allow installations from unknown sources?

Comment: @SushiHangover Yes it is

Comment: Correct ABI for the phone? If you install that `.apk` via `adb` do you get any additional errors?

Comment: in android command prompt type `keytool -genkeypair -v -keystore myname.keystore -alias myname -keyalg RSA \ -keysize 2048 -validity 10000` to create key store and then sign the apk file using properties window in VS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same error a few hours ago. Try to uninstall your app and then install the signed apk.

Comment: Does anyone have any explanation(s) why it's not working without uninstalling first?

Comment: I’d love to know as well. This is happening to me also.

Comment: I'd like to know that, too. I have the same issue with a signed ad-hoc installation.